# Swift dictionary silently doesn't store new items

Tags: swift, dictionary

I need some advice. Here is the code. I'm trying to add items to the Dictionary after deleting some of them. But nothing changes. Why? Where am I wrong?

This struct just as demo with `Equatable` protocol implemented.

```
struct Card: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return
            (lhs.color == rhs.color ||
                lhs.number == rhs.number ||
                lhs.shading == rhs.shading ||
                lhs.symbol == rhs.symbol)
    }
    var number = 0
    var symbol = 0
    var shading = 0
    var color = 0

    var isSelected = false
    var isSet = false
}
```

This is a card-game model, in this example just as demo to show

```
struct gameSet {
    var cards = [Card]()
    var cardField = [Int:Card]()

    init () {
        for num in 1...3 {
            for sym in 1...3 {
                for sha in 1...3 {
                    for col in 1...3 {
                        cards += [Card(number: num, symbol: sym, shading: sha, color: col, isSelected: false, isSet: false)]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Int's extension to get random numbers

```
extension Int {
    var random: Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
    }
}
var game = gameSet()

// cardField gets 24 random items from game.cards

var cardCount = 24

repeat {
    let randomCard = game.cards[(game.cards.count-1).random]
    game.cardField[game.cardField.count] = randomCard
    game.cards.remove(at: game.cards.index(of: randomCard)!)
    cardCount -= 1
} while cardCount != 0

// we got 24 items in cardField dictionary
print(game.cardField.count)

// delete 3 random items from cardField

for _ in 1...3 {
    let randomKey = game.cardField.count.random
    game.cardField.removeValue(forKey: randomKey)
}

// we got 21 items in cardField dictionary, ok
print(game.cardField.count)

// let's add 3 another items to cardField dictionary same way
var cardCount2 = 3

repeat {
    let randomCard = game.cards[(game.cards.count-1).random]
    game.cardField[game.cardField.count] = randomCard
    game.cards.remove(at: game.cards.index(of: randomCard)!)
    cardCount2 -= 1
} while cardCount2 != 0

// nothing changed! cardFiled still have 21 items as after deletion WHY???
print(game.cardField.count)
```

Is there any value - reference nuances, that I don't know about?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `&&`  in `static func ==` to check if *all* properties are identical?

Comment: No, question is not about protocol. Is about dictionary. I can't add values with keys that was used before and deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing random keys from dictionary and this might leave dic[21] value and your count is still 21. Then you are updating index 21 but count does not change. You can use array for cardFields also.

```
repeat {
    let randomCard = game.cards[(game.cards.count-1).random]
    game.cardField.append(randomCard)
    game.cards.remove(at: game.cards.index(of: randomCard)!)
    cardCount -= 1
} while cardCount != 0

// we got 24 items in cardField dictionary
print(game.cardField.count)

// delete 3 random items from cardField

for _ in 1...3 {
    let randomKey = game.cardField.count.random
    game.cardField.remove(at: randomKey)
}

// we got 21 items in cardField dictionary, ok
print(game.cardField.count)

// let's add 3 another items to cardField dictionary same way
var cardCount2 = 3

repeat {
    let randomCard = game.cards[(game.cards.count-1).random]
    game.cardField.append(randomCard)
    game.cards.remove(at: game.cards.index(of: randomCard)!)
    cardCount2 -= 1
} while cardCount2 != 0

// nothing changed! cardFiled still have 21 items as after deletion WHY???
print(game.cardField.count)
```